# Entity Framework EDMX force DateTime2

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, edmx

I'm working on some Database optimisation and I found that one of my main issue is that some queries are way slower using "exec sp_executesql" than raw SQL.
I'm thinking this has something to do with implicite datetime/datetime2 conversion because all the slow query are comparing dates.

At the end of the "exec sp_executesql" there is always something like that :

```
)))',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 datetime2(7),@p__linq__3 datetime2(7),@p__linq__4 datetime2(7),@p__linq__5 datetime2(7),@p__linq__6 datetime2(7),@p__linq__7 datetime2(7),@p__linq__8 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='2015-01-09 18:52:46.9264744',@p__linq__1='2015-01-09 18:52:16.926',@p__linq__2='2015-01-09 18:52:16.926',@p__linq__3='2015-01-09 18:52:16.926',@p__linq__4='2015-01-09 18:52:16.926',@p__linq__5='2015-01-09 18:52:16.926',@p__linq__6='2015-01-09 18:52:16.926',@p__linq__7='2015-01-09 18:52:16.926',@p__linq__8='2015-01-09 18:52:16.926';
```

In my database .NET DateTime are stored as datetime.
My model is generated from my EDMX.

Here is my question, should I change all my datetime fields or can I avoid this useless implicite conversion ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you truly measured the SQL performance difference? Could you give us some stats?

Comment: With exec sp_executesql 15 seconds, without < 0.1 second. That's all i know, i'm not sure about the datetime tho...

Comment: That's from the SQL Profiler ?

Comment: Yep, and some StopWatch

Comment: Stopwatch (I assume the C# class) will not give you true measurement of the SQL execution time. The first time EF or System.Data executes anything, there is a huge overhead associated with loading all the goodies, that make your programming life simpler. Track both statements with SQL Profiler, than report back.

Comment: I used both of them ;)

Comment: Could you give us screenshots of both SQL statements with stats from SQL Profiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm this behaviour (EF 6.1.0). The problem is the EF translated query prevents SQL server from using indexes (if your DateTime columns are indexed).
Example:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'... WHERE ([Extent1].[Timestamp] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Timestamp] <= @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='2014-03-01 0:00:00',@p__linq__1='2015-03-01 0:00:00'
```

Notice the difference between query condition(datetime) and parameters datatype(datetime2).

A quick workaround is to declare your DateTime parameters as nullable, which adds an additional CAST to the translated query conditions, indexes are used.

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'...WHERE ( CAST( [Extent1].[Timestamp] AS datetime2) >= @p__linq__0) AND ( CAST( [Extent1].[Timestamp] AS datetime2) <= @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='2014-03-01 0:00:00',@p__linq__1='2015-03-01 0:00:00'
```

This was supposedly fixed in [6.1.2](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/187), didn't have time to confirm it yet.